# How to create DataGridTextColumn of DataGrid dynamically and bind it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have two properties:

- `public ObservableCollection<Object>  HeaderOfDataGrid {get; set;}`
- `public Observablecollection<Object> BodyOfDataGrid {get; set;}`

Is it possible to bind `HeaderOfDataGrid` property to `DataGridTextColumn`? Yeah, I know that it is possible by binding like that:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Phone_Number}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

However, `HeaderOfDataGrid` property can have 'Count' equals 700 and I need to show all 700 items of collection `HeaderOfDataGrid` in `DataGridTextColumns` of `DataGrid`. So, I need to create 700 `DataGridTextColumns` based on `HeaderOfDataGrid` property(collection). Also, if `Count` of `HeaderOfDataGrid` property is 700, then `BodyOfDataGrid` property also has the same `Count`(for example, 700). So using hard-coded `xaml` is not convenient to me.

I know I can bind this way:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Body, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

But it is not what I want as I would like to renamed headers located in Header property.

How to implement binding and creating without hard-coded `xaml` to `DataGridTextColumn`?

Comment: If I get you correctly you are trying to build dynamic columns. You can programatically create your columns and in the DataGrid bind your collection of your columns. I would not suggest you create 700 columns. Rather chose a few to show and live up to the user to select what other columns they need to see. using a column chooser.

Comment: @TYY yeah, you are right, I am really tasked to show all 700 columns and create them dynamically cause I do not know what objects are going to show in DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found to do is to create `DataTable` and bound it to `DataGrid`:

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateDataGrid();
    }

    DataTable employeeDataTable = new DataTable();

    private void PopulateDataGrid()
    {
        var _ds = new DataSet("Test");

        employeeDataTable = _ds.Tables.Add("DT");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//create columns
        {   
            if(i==0)
                employeeDataTable.Columns.Add("Row");                
            employeeDataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//fill data to rows
        {
            var theRow = employeeDataTable.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    theRow[j] = (i + 1);
                    continue;
                }
                if (j % 2 == 0)                    
                    theRow[j] = "a";  
                else                  
                    theRow[j] = "b";
            }
            employeeDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow);
        }
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = employeeDataTable.AsDataView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it both ways.
If you want to rename the headers, you'll have to code it manually; otherwise you do it automatically and use what it gives you.

You may be able to set up a style, where the header is bound to a property of the underlying object. In that case it may work, but your `BodyOfDataGrid` would have to contain a `Header` property